# Foreach loop causes duplicate divs

Tags: php, arrays, join, foreach, duplicates

I have a join query which gives me a results array.

I have comments joined, and when I post a comment and have more than one comment, instead of placing it under the parent post, it duplicates it.

### My code

```
<div class="stream-posts">
    <?php if(isset($posts)): ?>
    <?php foreach(array_merge($posts) as $post): ?>
        <div id="stream_post_<?php echo $post['stream_id']; ?>" class="span6 stream-content">
            <span class="user"><a href="#"><?php echo $post['full_name']; ?> </a> <abbr class="stream-posted"><?php echo Date::time_ago( $post['date']) ?></abbr> </span>
            <p><?php echo Input::auto_link(Input::nl2br_limit($post['stream_text'], "2")); ?></p>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="feedback">
                <a href="#" class="like" rel="nofollow">Tetszik</a> - 
                <a href="#" class="comment" rel="nofollow">Hozzászólás</a>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="comments-text">
                    <?php if(count($post['like_id']) > 0): ?>
                        <?php echo count($post['like_id']); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            <div class="stream-comment">
                <form class="stream-comment-form">
                    <input type="hidden" name="comment_post" value="<?php echo $post['stream_id']; ?>">
                    <textarea name="comment_text"></textarea>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-mini pull-right">Hozzászólok</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

I know the `foreach` is the problem, and would like to ask is there a way to merge these results and not duplicate it?

I tried with `array_merge` but had no luck.

### Query

```
static function get_stream()
    {
        $query = DB::select()->from('stream_post');
        $query->join('stream_comment', 'LEFT');
        $query->on('stream_post.stream_id', '=', 'stream_comment.comment_stream_id');
        $query->join('stream_likes', 'LEFT');
        $query->on('stream_post.stream_id', '=', 'stream_likes.like_stream_id');
        $query->join('users_metadata');
        $query->on('stream_post.user_id', '=', 'users_metadata.user_id');
        $query->group_by('stream_post.stream_id');
        $query->order_by('stream_post.stream_id', 'DESC');
        $result = $query->execute();
        if(count($result) > 0) {    
            foreach($result as $row)
            {
                $data[] = $row;
            }

            return $data;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Your Query returns corect result?

Comment: how does the $posts array look like? can you give an example with the duplicates?

Comment: have you tried `array_unique()`?

Comment: first thank you for the down vote, i edited my question, thanks for all the help out guys

Comment: Why are you constantly closing and reopening PHP?

Answer (score 0):

`array_merge($posts)` will do nothing.

The problem must be the data that is in your `$posts` array, my guess with the data given is that you aren't doing a `GROUP BY` in your SQL query to pull the comments out, resulting in multiples coming out the database.

Comment: treid with that, tha problem with this variation is that it only swhows the first posted comment and not all